# Firefox search behavior changed in version 23, can I get the old behavior back?

Tags: firefox, search, feature-regression

Since the last Firefox update (23.0), it doesn't behave as it used to when you search something from the address bar.

Before v23, it used the default search engine (Google, by default), but now it uses the engine that is selected in the search box (which has the side effect of making the search box redundant)

I don't like this behavior at all, is there a way to restore the old behavior?

Comment: The only way would be through a plug-in

Comment: I've used Firefox for years and I've never seen a Firefox version that use google by default. It always use the selected engine in the search box, and it's much more convenient because sometimes I need to search something other than on google

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several add-ons to augment the address bar search functionality.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/keywordurl-hack/ (I use this. Install it and change the `keyword.URL` property in `about:config`.)

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/keyword-search/ (This one looks a little more usable, and appears to address your problem specifically.)

Comment: Awesome, it's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot

Comment: keyword.URL doesn't comes up in firefox 25.0 in debian squeeze with keyword url hack

Answer (score 1):

A perfect plugin for you would be Firefox's [InstantFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/instantfox/)

Answer (score -1):

You can go to about:config and then add a string named "keyword.URL" (case sensitive) and set the value to http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=navclient&btnI=1&q= which used to be the default in older firefox versions.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Can you please add the source from where you got this answer (if any) ?

Comment: This does not work in FF23 or later.